# Has there been any research on the "take rate" of conifer cuttings?

Tags: cuttings, evergreens, conifers, rooting-hormone

So I can see that a conifer cuttings method can be done in August +/-.

https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-take-conifer-cuttings/

Has there been any research on this "take rate"?

I.e. 100 cuttings were put in soil and 1 year later 10 cuttings had rooted and were in a good position to survive to year 2.

Answer (score 2):

That extract you quote from applies to deciduous trees, not coniferous ones. Coniferous trees are propagated using semi ripe cuttings from the current season's growth, preferably taken in late summer, and not from hardwood cuttings done in the way you mention. Instructions on how to do them here https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-take-conifer-cuttings/. The cuttings are placed into pots in a warm (but not hot) place - there is usually a high success rate if the cuttings are processed correctly, and this is the preferred method of propagation in the horticultural industry because it is more successful than from seed.

UPDATE: I note you have changed your question from the way it was originally and have asked a slightly different question. I don't believe you will find statistics  for  successful cutting rates for conifers generally - for one thing, there are many types of conifers, and some may root more readily than others. Successful cuttings depend on the method used, how well they are prepared, the environment, viability of the cuttings and not least, which coniferous plant the cuttings are from - Abies or Thuja, Picea or Juniper may make a difference, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my reference. Anyone have an answer to the question though?

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Thanks, Bamboo:  Understandable that "Successful cuttings depend on: the method used, how well they are prepared, the environment, viability of the cuttings and not least, which coniferous plant the cuttings are from." Has there been any study on any combination of these attributes? So that if there were 10 studies, we could take the lowest rate and the highest rate from 2 of the papers and say that, the take rate is between 63% and 92% or maybe it is lower and the answer would be more useless, like 0.2% and 42%

Comment: If there are stats like that, they're likely divided between types of coniferous trees rather than the very broad 'conifer' definition, but I don't know of any. Usually, you look up the specific tree you want to propagate and follow the recommended method for that tree, because the recommended method is the most successful or it wouldn't be recommended. Its usual to take more cuttings than you need to allow for failures.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a vey few conifers like yew, I doubt conifers can generally be grown from cuttings.

Comment: In fact, most conifers are propagated from semi ripe cuttings in the horticultural industry

Comment: I am surprised ; I bet spruce, pine, fir, Douglas fir , are not grown from cuttings.

Comment: Having spent four days doing cuttings from conifers as part of my horticultural training, I can assure you most are, especially named varieties. I was bored stiff those four days...

Comment: So , once in my life I am wrong.